# How to implement the OWASP ESAPI validator with groups of validation attempts in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml, esapi

I have been playing around with the OWASP ESAPI utilities that are included with ColdFusion 9. [ColdFusion's Builtin Enterprise Security API](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/788.cfm). The `encoder` utilities are pretty straight forward and I believe I have them working fine. My problem is with the `validator` utilities.

I can get them to work *singly*. That is, if I call the `validator.getValidInput()` method with "invalid" data it will throw an error that I can catch. However, when I try to call the `validator` method in *batch* I get a null pointer exception. By *batch* I mean attempting to execute groups of validation attempts. This is supposed to work by passing the `validator.getValidInput()` method a `ValidationErrorList` parameter which should tell it NOT to throw an error but instead just add the error to the error list. I cannot get it to work in this mode. My best attempt is giving me a null pointer exception.

Here is the specific error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

With this stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator.getValidInput(DefaultValidator.java:238) at 
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor377.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
coldfusion.runtime.StructBean.invoke(StructBean.java:536) at 
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2393) at 
cftest2ecfm989071068.runPage(D:\Web\internet\fboc\test.cfm:19) at 
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231) at 
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416) at 
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722) at 
cfApplication2ecfc1705903666$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(D:\Web\internet\fboc\Application.cfc:70) at 
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at 
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405) at 
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368) at 
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55) at 
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at 
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220) at 
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491) at 
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337) at 
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:88) at 
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:280) at 
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:356) at 
coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at 
coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at 
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94) at 
coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70) at 
coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79) at 
coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at 
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at 
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46) at 
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at 
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at 
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at 
coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126) at 
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:201) at 
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at 
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86) at 
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at 
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at 
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94) at 
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101) at 
jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106) at 
jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42) at 
jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286) at 
jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543) at 
jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203) at 
jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428) at 
jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Here is a simple test script. You will notice that I have one line commented out. That line works without the `ErrorList` but throws an error (as it should). I am trying to get the method to work without throwing the error:

```
<cftry>
<cfsilent>
<cfparam name="form.TestField" default="" type="string" />

<cfset Esapi = CreateObject("java", "org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI") />
<cfset EsapiEncoder = Esapi.encoder() />
<cfset EsapiValidator = Esapi.validator() />

<cfset Clean = StructNew() />
<cfset Clean.Css = EsapiEncoder.encodeForCss(form.TestField) />
<cfset Clean.Html = EsapiEncoder.encodeForHtml(form.TestField) />
<cfset Clean.HtmlAttribute = EsapiEncoder.encodeForHtmlAttribute(form.TestField) />
<cfset Clean.JavaScript = EsapiEncoder.encodeForJavaScript(form.TestField) />
<cfset Clean.Url = EsapiEncoder.encodeForUrl(form.TestField) />
<cfset Clean.Xml = EsapiEncoder.encodeForXml(form.TestField) />

<cfset ErrorList = CreateObject("java", "org.owasp.esapi.ValidationErrorList") />
<cfset Valid = StructNew() />
<cfset Valid.Input = EsapiValidator.getValidInput("Test Field", form.TestField, "SafeString", 128, false, true, ErrorList) />
<!---<cfset Valid.Input = EsapiValidator.getValidInput("Test Field", form.TestField, "SafeString", 128, false, true) />--->
</cfsilent>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <title>ESAPI Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>ESAPI Test</h3>
        <cfoutput>
        <form name="frmtest" id="frmtest" action="#cgi.script_name#" method="post">
            <p>Enter text to test:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="TestField" id="TestField" size="64" maxlength="128" value="#Clean.HtmlAttribute#" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value=" Submit " /></p>
        </form>
        </cfoutput>
        <hr />
        <cfdump var="#Clean#" label="Clean Structure" />
        <hr />
        <cfdump var="#Valid#" label="Valid Structure" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<cfcatch type="any">
    <hr />
    <div>
        <h3>ERROR</h3>
        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" label="Error" />
    </div>
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

When I run this script with "valid" data it works fine (no errors thrown). If I enter an "invalid" character then I get the null pointer exception.

Example of "valid" data: `this is a safe string 0123456789`
Example of "invalid" data: `this is a safe string 0123456789-` (notice the hyphen at the end)

[Here is a link to the documentation for the validator.getValidInput method that I am trying to implement](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultValidator.html#getValidInput%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean,%20org.owasp.esapi.ValidationErrorList%29).

[Here is a link to the documentation that shows what I am trying to implement](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/ValidationErrorList.html).

For what it's worth, the validation "rules" are defined in the `validation.properties` file that comes with ColdFusion. That file is located in the {cfusion lib} directory. Here are the contents of that file from my server:

```
# The ESAPI validator does many security checks on input, such as canonicalization
# and whitelist validation. Note that all of these validation rules are applied *after*
# canonicalization. Double-encoded characters (even with different encodings involved,
# are never allowed.
#
# To use:
#
# First set up a pattern below. You can choose any name you want, prefixed by the word
# "Validation." For example:
#   Validation.Email=^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
# 
# Then you can validate in your code against the pattern like this:
#     ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("User Email", input, "Email", maxLength, allowNull);
# Where maxLength and allowNull are set for you needs, respectively.
#
# But note, when you use boolean variants of validation functions, you lose critical 
# canonicalization. It is preferable to use the "get" methods (which throw exceptions) and 
# and use the returned user input which is in canonical form. Consider the following:
#  
# try {
#    someObject.setEmail(ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("User Email", input, "Email", maxLength, allowNull));
#
Validator.SafeString=^[.\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}]{0,1024}$
Validator.Email=^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
Validator.IPAddress=^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
Validator.URL=^(ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.\\?\\,\\:\\'\\/\\\\\\+=&amp;%\\$#_]*)?$
Validator.CreditCard=^(\\d{4}[- ]?){3}\\d{4}$
Validator.SSN=^(?!000)([0-6]\\d{2}|7([0-6]\\d|7[012]))([ -]?)(?!00)\\d\\d\\3(?!0000)\\d{4}$
Validator.CFContainerID=^[\\p{Alnum}_\\-\\.:]+$
Validator.GOOGLEMAPAPI=^[\\p{Alnum}_\\+=\\/\\-]+$
Validator.CFFORMSCRIPTSRC=^[^\\*\\?\"'<>|%]*$
```

I presume that the idea is to add rules to this file for your own applications.

Has anyone gotten the `validator.getValidInput()` method to work in *batch* (groups of validation attempts)?

**Update 1**

I noticed that the following is being written to my `cfusion-out.log` on the server every time I get the null pointer exception. It leads me to believe that it is working to a point but then gets a null pointer while attempting to assign the validation exception:

```
06/25 16:08:14 [jrpp-3225] WARN  [SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown -> /IntrusionDetector] Invalid input: context=Test Field, type(SafeString)=^[.\p{Alnum}\p{Space}]{0,1024}$, input=this is a safe string 0123456789-
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException: Test Field: Invalid input. Please conform to regex ^[.\p{Alnum}\p{Space}]{0,1024}$ with a maximum length of 128
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.checkWhitelist(StringValidationRule.java:144)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.checkWhitelist(StringValidationRule.java:160)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.getValid(StringValidationRule.java:284)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator.getValidInput(DefaultValidator.java:199)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator.getValidInput(DefaultValidator.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at coldfusion.runtime.StructBean.invoke(StructBean.java:508)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2393)
at cftest2ecfm989071068.runPage(D:\Web\internet\fboc\test.cfm:19)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
at cfApplication2ecfc1705903666$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(D:\Web\internet\fboc\Application.cfc:70)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:491)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:337)
at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:88)
at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:280)
at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:356)
at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)
at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79)
at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:201)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

**Update 2**

I have been digging through [Damon Miller's implementation of the OWASP ESAPI](https://github.com/damonmiller/esapi4cf/blob/master/esapi4cf/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultValidator.cfc) methods for ColdFusion. I noticed in his code that he does not call the `getValidInput()` method with the `ValidationErrorList` attribute. Rather he wrote the code to catch the generated error and then add the error to the list himself.  Hmmm?  I thought the method was supposed to do that for you????

As an aside, I am trying not to use a library such as his to avoid the additional bloat that I do not need.

Excerpt from his code:

```
if(structKeyExists( arguments, "errorList" )) {
        try {
            return getValidInput( arguments.context, arguments.input, arguments.type, arguments.maxLength, arguments.allowNull );
        }
        catch(esapi4cf.org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException e) {
            arguments.errorList.addError( arguments.context, e );
        }
        return arguments.input;
    }
    else {
    ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in the Coldfusion implementation of ESAPI - we have full coverage testing of the getValidInput method in your unit test suite for ESAPI that demonstrate that the method works as advertised.

Based off of your second update above I would guess that in the CF implementation code there is an uninitialized variable being accessed (perhaps errorList is uninitialized in this context)

I am the project leader of the OWASP ESAPI project and very familiar with this bit of code in ESAPI itself but am not a CF developer and have not seen all of the implementation code for CF9.

** **Edit** **

In order to make the validation methods work in batch using ColdFusion a call to the `init()` method is required for the `org.owasp.esapi.ValidationErrorList` class *before* calling the `validator` methods. Add the following line to the test script and it will work:

```
<cfset ErrorList = ErrorList.init() />
```

In context:

```
<cfset ErrorList = CreateObject("java", "org.owasp.esapi.ValidationErrorList") />
<cfset ErrorList = ErrorList.init() />
<cfset Valid.TestField = EsapiValidator.getValidInput("Test Field", form.TestField, "SafeString", 128, true, true, ErrorList) />
```

Now when invalid input is entered the error will be added to the `ErrorList` variable instead of throwing an error.

Comment: Ohh man .. @Miguel-F - You are not going to believe it.. Chris' comment about initialized variables is right. For some reason you need to explicitly call `init()` on the list *before* using it. CF should instantiate it automatically, but for whatever reason it does not, but call `init()` and the NPE goes away. Good spot Chris!

Comment: Wow!, just wow! Chris thank you so much for coming here and answering. You and Leigh are correct, by calling the `init()` method on the error list the null pointer error goes away and `getValidInput()` works as documented. @Leigh did you by chance test this with CF10? I will enter a bug with Adobe under CF9 (and CF10 if you can confirm).  @Chris if it is okay with you I will edit your answer to include the ColdFusion code necessary to make my test script work.

Comment: Here is a link to the bug I entered for CF 9 - [https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3595899](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3595899)  Can anyone confirm (or deny) this issue in CF 10?

Comment: @Miguel-F - It still exists in 10,283111. Chris - Thanks again for chiming in and solving the mystery! (Wish I could up vote this a few more times :).

Comment: @Leigh - thanks for confirming. I will add a bug for CF10 as well. Can you tell me what OS and Java version you are running as well (for the bug details)?

Comment: @Miguel-F - I am not near my old dev machine right now, but its: XP and I *think* jvm 1.6.0.41.

Comment: @Leigh - thanks. Here is a link to the bug I entered for CF 10 - [https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3595943](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3595943)