# Getting proper HTML encoded values from an input textfield

Tags: html, forms, coldfusion

I have a text field which people can type anything they want in. However, when I get the value from the text field I want to return the values encoded so that quotes get a value like `&quot;` instead of plain `"`.

I need this because the plain values are causing me problems later on in the site when using them in HTML attribute such as description meta tag.

Is there a way to get the proper HTML code for special characters from an `<input type="text"/>` form element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you didn't specify any programming language, you can use the `htmlspecialchars()` function in PHP for this. You would just need to use:

`echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['inputname']);`

See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for more info.

Comment: very nice, I just discovered ColdFusion has htmlEditFormat() which does the same thing

Comment: No problem. In PHP there's also a `htmlspecialchars_decode()` function that you can use to convert anything with values encoded back into their special characters. I'm not sure if ColdFusion has something similar - you'll have to check that :)

Comment: If you're using cf 10+ you can use the encodefor* functions (encodeforHTML() specifically). Htmleditformat() for cf9 and older.

Answer (score 3):

ColdFusion actually includes the OWASP ESAPI utilities that are specifically intended for this dating back to ColdFusion 8 (if updated with the appropriate security hot fix). See this article from Pete Freitag - [ColdFusion's Builtin Enterprise Security API](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/788.cfm)

> One of the nice side effects to installing the latest ColdFusion security hotfix is that ColdFusion 8 and ColdFusion 9 now both include the jar files for the OWASP ESAPI or Enterprise Security API.
>
> This means that it’s now very very easy to leverage this powerful security API from within your ColdFusion code.
>
> Here's a quick example of how you might use the ESAPI encoder to prevent cross site scripting:
>
> `<cfset esapi = CreateObject("java", "org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI")>`
>   `<cfset esapiEncoder = esapi.encoder()>`
>   `<cfoutput><p>Hello #esapiEncoder.encodeForHTML(url.name)#</p></cfoutput>`
>
> The Encoder class has methods for encoding all kinds of input so they can be safely used in various contexts. Here’s a listing some handy encoders:
>
> encodeForHTML - used for encoding a string between HTML tags.
>   encodeForHTMLAttribute - used for encoding a string inside of a HTML attribute.
>   encodeForURL - used for encoding inside of a url, eg: in a href.
>   encodeForJavaScript - used for an input inside a javascript variable or in a function argument.
>   encodeForCSS - used for encoding variable inside of CSS (eg inline style attributes).
>   encodeForXML - encoding variables inside XML.
>   encodeForXPath - encode variables in an XPath query.
>
> What else can ESAPI do?
>
> ESAPI also provides helpers for Validation, Encryption, Logging, Randomization, and more. Checkout the docs to see what it can do.

The new security functions `encodeFor*` beginning with ColdFusion 10 are actually an implementation of these utilities. [ColdFusion 10 Provides Powerful New Security Tools](http://blogs.adobe.com/security/2012/05/coldfusion-10-provides-powerful-new-security-tools.html)

- [EncodeForHTML](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForHTML)
- [EncodeForCSS](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForCSS)
- [EncodeForHTMLAttribute](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForHTMLAttribute)
- [EncodeForJavaScript](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForJavaScript)
- [EncodeForURL](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForURL)
- [EncodeForXML](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForXML)

These utilities do much more for you than `htmlEditFormat()` will. As noted they include specific encoding/decoding functions for the various contexts; HTML, HTML attributes, URL, JavaScript, CSS, XML and XPath. They also include validation for the same. I would encourage you to check them out. I have previously posted a question on how to implement validation using these utilities which may help you - [How to implement the OWASP ESAPI validator with groups of validation attempts in ColdFusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17304845/1636917)

Reference - [OWASP Enterprise Security API](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery. See this post on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667335/Client-side-HTML-Encode-and-Decode-functions-with)

Answer (score 1):

this removes only the few important charecters and you dont have to add a big library to achieve this

```
var HTML_ENTITIES = {
'&': '&amp;',
'>': '&gt;',
'<': '&lt;',
'"': '&quot;',
"'": '&#39;'
};


// HTML escaping
htmlEscape = function(text) {
return text && text.replace(/[&"'><]/g, function(character) {
  return HTML_ENTITIES[character];
});
};
```

Hope this helps